# Linux alternative to fiddler for windows auroresponder function

Tags: proxy, debugging, https

I got debugg an website with its assets in production easily, but i don`t seem to find any good alternative to it on ubuntu.

the only feature i am looking for is: I need something that decript the http request of a javascript file, and replace with the local file a javascript. In order for me to test changes in code without having to put into production.

Comment: That should be in your Question above, not buried in a comment.

Comment: Question makes no sense. There also is no info in it that tells me it has any thing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/fiddler/

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Fiddler before, in fact I have never heard of it!
Due to my lack of understanding of this program in particular, my recommended program may not be the best, however have you tried mtimproxy? It seems to do what Fiddler can do.
I hope that helped.

Comment: I checked it out, but it seems a little too much for me to config, and i dont know if it will suit my use, I need something exactly like fiddler autorresponder function.